# gdx-ai: how to disable behaviour

Tags: java, android, libgdx, gdx-ai

From yesterday I was looking for a way to disable some behaviour in Gdx-Ai, I wrote code like this:

```
arriveSteeringBehaviour = new Arrive<Vector3>(character, MainCharacter.getTarget()) //
                .setTimeToTarget(0.1f)
                .setArrivalTolerance(0.0002f)
                .setDecelerationRadius(8);

arriveSteeringBehaviour.setEnabled(true);
character.setSteeringBehavior(arriveSteeringBehaviour);
```

when "Arrive Distance" <= "Deceleration Radius" I'm trying to disable the Arrive Behaviour like this

```
if (arriveSteeringBehaviour.getDistance() <= arriveSteeringBehaviour.getDecelerationRadius() ) {
    arriveSteeringBehaviour.setEnabled(false);
    character.setSteeringBehavior(null);
}
```

but it's doesn't worked, character object still moving around, anyone can figure this out? thanks

note: in update method, I did disable any translation also disabled character.update(GdxAI.getTimepiece().getDeltaTime()); line.

Comment: Were you able to confirm that the problem wasn't in your criteria? (i.e. that the if statement was being evaluated as true)

Comment: thanks John, yeah I did some debuging and loging too and I'm sure the if statement executed normally..